# Disconnect from a Wi-Fi network in Android 10 in a more "generic" way

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-10.0

I have a bunch of Wi-Fi devices that I need to connect to, do/send some commands and then disconnect.

I connect to them using `connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(myRequest, myNetworkCallback);`
Then I do the required actions, and by doing so my app navigates to multiple pages. 
When everything is finished I want to disconnect from the device.

To achieve this I need to call `connectivityManager.UnregisterNetworkCallback(myNetworkCallback);`

The issue I have is that I want to have the Connect() and Disconnect() methods as two independent commands, and not having to save "myNetworkCallback" to pass it inside Disconnect().

I don't need to keep the network saved in any way and I permanently know the Ssid of it.

Is there a way to completely drop this network without having to pass the callback as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass any parameters , you could just create a **NetworkCallback** without any properties .

Create a subclass of **ConnectivityManager**

```
public class SubConnectivityManager : ConnectivityManager
    {
        public SubConnectivityManager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }

        public void CustomUnregisterNetworkCallback()
        {
            this.UnregisterNetworkCallback(new NetworkCallback());
        }

    }
```

```
SubConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (SubConnectivityManager)this.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.ConnectivityService);
connectivityManager.CustomUnregisterNetworkCallback();
```